# UnsatisfiedLinkError with maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, teamcity, maven-surefire-plugin

When running a unit test with the *maven-surefire-plugin*, this error occures:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

I know how to cope with this problem in my IDE, I simply have to select the correct runtime JRE in the test's run configuration. However, when the test is run on a TeamCity build server, the error mentioned above occurs.

Is there any surefire or TeamCity option to configure the runtime JRE?

This is my current surefire configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*Test.java</include>
    </includes>
    <parallel>methods</parallel>
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring a *Maven* build step in *TeamCity*, select a target JDK with the appropriate "bitness" (x86 in your case):

[image]

At least one of your build agents should have a 32-bit JDK discovered and available. You can check whether this is the case for a particular agent by Agents -> Connected ->  -> Agent Parameters -> Environment Variables. Here's an example of `JDK_*` variables with their values:

```
JDK_14       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.4.2_19
JDK_15       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22
JDK_15_x64   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_22
JDK_16       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
JDK_16_x64   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
JDK_17       C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_76
JDK_17_x64   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_76
JDK_18       C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
JDK_18_x64   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
```

Here, `JDK_18` and `JDK_18_x64` having the same value means that the agent hasn't found a 32-bit 1.8 JDK.

Comment: ``<jvm>${env.JDK_18}/bin/java</jvm>`` fixed the problem on TeamCity, but now the build fails locally. I tried using ``<environmentVariables>`` to set the variable in my surefire configuration, but it did not work.

Comment: Is there any way to set a different path locally and make TeamCity override it with the agent's ``JDK_18`` environment variable?

Comment: @user1438038: The idea is to leave `pom.xml` intact, but rather change the TeamCity Maven build step parameters. In order for your build to succeed, you need to modify either one, not both. [Fabien Thouraud](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3004076/fabien-thouraud)'s answer is about changing the `pom`. Mine is about TeamCity fine tuning.

Comment: All right, thanks for putting that straight. I managed to copy my build configuration, detach the build step from the template and change the target JDK as desired. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jvm` tag to specify which JVM to use :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <jvm>${env.MY_JAVA_HOME}/bin/java</jvm>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This example assumes that you have a `MY_JAVA_HOME` environment variable.

Comment: The ``jvm`` option is fine as long as I know a JRE path on my local machine. But how do I select a proper JRE installed on the TeamCity build server?

Comment: As far as I know you can't have 2 Java installations directly accessible unless you define a specific environment variable pointing to non default Java. If you don't know where the 64 bits JRE is installed I have no solution. In the contrary, you can add environment variable by editing `buildAgent.properties` TeamCity configuration file.

Comment: The given configuration in particular for `includes` is exactly the default of Maven surefire-plugin...so no need to explicit configure this.